# Push notification in my apps

Tags: xamarin

I have a published app and now I want users to receive new information through push notifications, I've been doing a search and I found the firebase, what I was left in doubt and how to add the messages outside the Firebase account.
I have a sql server database system where I am saving my info and want to know how can I work so that when added a new information already appears in the push notification

How can I create my own notification server without using firebase? Am I required to use a messaging server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is one of the best and optimised approach to integrate the push notification in your application. Go through this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121218/Android-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-Tutorial) to setup your application on the FCM console for any `android` app. For `IOS` use the [component](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging) to get the sample code. Once you are done with the set up on the FCM console, try to send a push notification from FCM console. If it is received then your client(App) code is working fine.

Now in order to set up a server side utility to trigger a push notification, there are three ways to send the push notification:

- Send message to particular device using device token.
- Send message to topics subscribed by client app - [Refer link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)
- Send message to device group - [Refer link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)

Use the below `C#` server side code to send the messages to particular client app using device token:

```
WebRequest objRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
string jsonNotificationMessageFormat = "{\"to\":\"device_token_id\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"This is the title\",\"body\":\"This is the body of message\",\"icon\":\"icon_name\",\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonNotificationMessageFormat);
objRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
objRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
objRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
objRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
objRequest.Method = "post";

    using (Stream dataStream = objRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        using (WebResponse objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                {
                    String responseFromFirebaseServer = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The `serverKey` and `senderId` is available in the cloud messaging tab of the firebase console’s project settings pane, once you are done with configuration of the application on the FCM console.

**Note:** Each and every time the application is installed on any device, the `device_token` for that device changes, therefore you need to the update the `device_token` in the web service request.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to create custom Service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html , which is holding connection via socket or polling some remote server with intervals.

But, I suggest that Firebase service is more advanced and optimized in battery consumption and, particularly, in utilizing the sleep mode. It's not trivial to make a service which will have fast response and CPU consumption. I think that a custom service development will lead to native (C++) coding of networking routines libs.

Also, take into account that Firebase provides own Authentication service with ability to seamless convert your anonymous user to registered. There is a lot of pros of Firebase services. And cons are: your users have to install Google Play Services, if your app will grow - you will pay to Firebase.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira a aplicação no projeto de desktop or web C # incluir essas mensagens, fora da firebase?